# issue when promoting a second server as domain on r2 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm in an odd situatuion here,

I've upgraded my network to a 2008 domain from a 2003 with out any issue, this works fine and all the FSMO are in one DC,

I was about to install a second domain on a 2008R2 and this error is coming up again and again.

I The problem is I keep getting an area telling me that I need to run adprep /domainPrep /forestPrep, but when I run it on the First DC, it tells me this has already been run and updated and it is aborted. Does anyone have any ideas on why I can't add a Server 2008 machine as a domain controller?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running adprep from the R2 DVD on the older 2008 system? R2 has its own active directory modifications.

If your older DC is a 32 bit system you will need to run the 32 bit adprep rather than the 64 bit one.

Ian